# NSToolbar with modal windows in swift

Tags: swift, modal-dialog, nstoolbar

I'm trying to add a preferences Windows for my application.
It's a modal segue from the "Preferences" menu.

When i launch the application, the windows open but i can't see the Toolbar.

[image]

If i change the segue to "show", then it works fine.

[image]

Any idea why ?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Comment: To answer my own, you do not do that .. You can use a TabView with the Toolbar option

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own, you do not do that.
You can use a TabView with the Toolbar option